Field Extension of Local Fields of Degree $d$ containing $d$th root of unity
Let $L_w/K_v$ a finite degree $d=[L_w:K_v]$ Galois extension of $p$-adic fields (ie $L_w,K_v$ are finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$).
Assume moreover that $d $ is coprime to $p^{\kappa}-1$, where $p^{\kappa}= \vert \mathcal{O}_{K_v}/ \mathfrak{m}_K \vert$ is the cardinality of residue field of $K_v$.
Question: Are there any criterion known to chracterize when $L_w$ contains $\zeta_d$, the $d$th root of unity? Equivalently, when $L_w$ includes the field $K_v(\zeta_d)$?
The question is motivated by the case $K_v= \Bbb Q_p, L_w= \Bbb Q_p(\sqrt[d]{p})$ where is additionally assumed that $d$ is not divisible by $p$. Here, the above always holds as this $L_w$ contains $\sqrt[d]{p}$ and $\sqrt[d]{p} \cdot \zeta_d$ as $X^d-p$ is irreducibly by Eisenstein criterion.
Is there any "deeper" characterization when $L_w$ then just that the degree of a (...and therefore of all) irreducible polynomial of cyclotomic polynomial divides $d$?
It suggests presumably to treat cases $d$ divisible by $p$ (=totally ramified case) and $(d,p)=1$ separately.
(If that's still to broad to have a qualitave result, can we get something if we impose so additional assumptions on the considered extension? Eg, additionally assume that it is Abelian. Or focus on the case $K_v= \Bbb Q_p$; but maybe there are more "natural" specifications for this problem)

As to your example: isn't the residue field of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[d]{p})$ just $\mathbb{F}_p$, which does not contain $\zeta_d$ for all $d$ with $p\nmid d$?

@Mastrem: You mean the residue field - which is indeed $\Bbb F_p$ as the extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ you are refering to is totally ramified -  not contains $\zeta_d$ with $d \nmid p-1$, right? Then yes.

recall that $\Bbb F_p^{\times} \cong \Bbb Z/(p-1)$ (as group), but $(p-1)$ th root is contained in residue field even though $p \nmid (p-1)$. Please correct me if I misread what you intended to state?

I mean the residue field contains $\zeta_d$ for some $d$ with $p\nmid d$, but not for all of those $d$, which you seem to suggest. In general, if $p\nmid d$ and if $\ell$ is the residue field of $L$, we have $\zeta_d\in L$ if and only if $m\mid [\ell:\mathbb{F}_p]$, where $m$ is the order of $p$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$. So if $(d,p\phi(d))=1$, we have $\zeta_d\in L$ if and only if $\zeta_d\in K$.

@Mastrem: in last sentence you assume $K =\Bbb Q_p$, right?

No. Let $k$ be the residue field of $K$. $\zeta_d\in L$ is equivalent to $m\mid [\ell:\mathbb{F}_p]=[\ell:k]\cdot [k:\mathbb{F}_p]$. Now, $m\mid \phi(d)$ and $[\ell:k]\mid d$, so if $(d,\phi(d))=1$, this is equivalent to $m\mid [k:\mathbb{F}_p]$, which is equivalent to $\zeta_d \in K$.

@Mastrem: But what about following example which seemingly contradicts to that $\zeta_d \in L$ iff $\zeta_d \in K$ under assumption $(d, p \phi(d))=1$: Let $q$ pe any prime $q >p$ , $L := \Bbb Q_p(\zeta_q)$ and $K:= \Bbb Q_p$. Set $ d:=q$. Then $(d, p \phi(d))=1$ as $\phi(q)=q-1$ ( as $q$ prime by assumtn), $\zeta_d \in L$ by construction, but $\zeta_d \not \in K$, compare with discussion here

You defined $d:=[L:K]$ in your post... In particular, in your example we must have $d\mid q-1$, so $d\neq q$.

@Mastrem: right, sorry, I missed to take the assumed property for €$d$ actually into account. Could you maybe elaborate the argument of your claim on the case $p \nmid d$ that $\zeta_d \in L$ iff $\text{ord}_{(\Bbb Z/d)^{\times}} \mid [\ell:\Bbb F_p]$?

First, if $p\nmid d$, then $X^d-1$ has no double roots in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. You can use this to show that $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ contains primitive $d$'th roots of unity. (This is where things go wrong if $p\mid d$).
Now, $\mathbb{F}{p}(\zeta_d)=\mathbb{F}{p^m}$ for some $m\ge 1$. We know that $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}={\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}:\alpha^{p^m}=\alpha}$, so $m$ is the smallest positive integer for which $\zeta_d^{p^m}=\zeta_d$.

@Mastrem: I see, and the converse follows just from standard fact for finite fields that $\Bbb F_{p^m} \subset  \Bbb F_{p^n} $ iff $m \mid n$ and as $p \nmid d$ everything is already said on level of residue fields

Since one shouldn't answer a question in the comments, I wrote up a quick answer.
Let $\ell$ and $k$ be the residue fields of $L$ and $K$ respectively and assume that $p\nmid d$. Let $m$ be the order of $p$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$. Then $\zeta_d\in L$ if and only if $\zeta_d\in \ell$, by Hensel, and $\zeta_d\in \ell$ if and only if $m\mid [\ell:\mathbb{F}_p]$.
This shows that, in general, we cannot decide whether $\zeta_d\in L$ without knowing which roots of unity are contained in $K$. For example, if $(d,\phi(d))=1$, we have $\zeta_d\in L$ if and only if $\zeta_d\in K$.

are there any interesting results known adressing the case $p \mid d$?

That case is harder, since $\mathbb{Q}p(\zeta{p^n})$ is totally ramified, and whereas $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has a unique unramified extension of any given degree (which allows for a simple condition on the residue class degree when $p\nmid d$), this is not the case for ramified extensions, making such a simple condition impossible.
